# A library for Extraction of an archive file

Tags: c++, c, linux, freebsd

I need a library to list files in archives  and to extract archive files. The library should support archive types as much as possible. Do you have any suggestion ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: zlib http://zlib.net/manual.html perhaps ?

Comment: zlib api is so complicated. do you have any sample code of using zlib ?

Comment: tried anything on yourself? if so, what?

Comment: You can always use the built in unix tools for extracting files. Like tar, gzip and etc.

Comment: Well, 7-Zip is open source and it supports a lot of archive types. I'm not sure how usable it is, though. Maybe you can get some inspiration from this: http://www.progdigy.com/?page_id=13

Comment: 7zip is pretty good. But i didnt find a library version. Also   tar, gzip, etc.  are like 7zip.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sounds like you are looking for libarchive http://libarchive.github.com/

Comment: libarchive is a part of FreeBSD, has been for a decade or so.